# Combine Rows MS Access (SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to combine rows to merge into one single row of the data for the following scenario. would really appreciate any help here. I'm trying this in MSAccess

[image]

I would like result as 1 row which has earliest INSTOREDATE  which is 21-Jan-19, total of TOTALBUY(10000+300+4000+2475=16,775). below is the result i am expecting

[image]

Comment: GROUP BY, MIN(), SUM() etc.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images... And it's MS Access...

Comment: Looks like a simple aggregate query. Or build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calc in footer.

Comment: thanks.. let me try these..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SEASON,
         PHASE,
         STYLEBR,
         COLOURCODE,
         INSTOREDATE,
         TICKETRETAIL,
         SUM(TOTALBUY) AS TOTAL
FROM YourTable
```

or

```
       SELECT SEASON,
        PHASE,
        STYLEBR,
        COLOURCODE,
        INSTOREDATE,
        TICKETRETAIL,
        SUM(TOTALBUY) AS TOTAL
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY  SEASON, PHASE, STYLEBR, COLOURCODE, INSTOREDATE, TICKETRETAIL
```

Comment: This did help.. Thanks a lot